interacting with chrome without selenium
here is what i want to do
i want to create a python script that search for a keywoard in youtube ' i'm not using selenium or a webdriver ' then i want the code to scroll until it finds my video which i will give  it's exact title , url and channel name if needed, i can even give a screen shot of the video thumbnail.
how can i achieve this ?
code below is generated by ai
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def find_video(keyword, video_title, video_url, channel_name, thumbnail_url):
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()

    # Navigate to YouTube and search for the keyword
    await page.goto(f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={keyword}")

    # Function to check if the current video matches the desired video
    async def video_matches(element):
        video_info = await page.evaluate("""(element) => {
            const title = element.querySelector('#video-title').innerText;
            const url = element.querySelector('#video-title').href;
            const channel = element.querySelector('#channel-name').innerText;
            const thumbnail = element.querySelector('#thumbnail').src;
            return { title, url, channel, thumbnail };
        }""", element)

        return (
            video_info["title"] == video_title
            and video_info["url"] == video_url
            and video_info["channel"] == channel_name
            and video_info["thumbnail"] == thumbnail_url
        )

    # Scroll until the desired video is found
    while True:
        video_elements = await page.querySelectorAll("#dismissible")
        for video_element in video_elements:
            if await video_matches(video_element):
                await browser.close()
                return video_url

        await page.evaluate("window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)  # Wait for the page to load new content

# Example usage
keyword = "python tutorial"
video_title = "Python for Beginners - Full Course"
video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw"
channel_name = "freeCodeCamp.org"
thumbnail_url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rfscVS0vtbw/hqdefault.jpg"

async def main():
    result = await find_video(keyword, video_title, video_url, channel_name, thumbnail_url)
    print(f"Found video URL: {result}")

asyncio.run(main())


You haven't explained what the problem is. Edit your question and explain what the problem is. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

the bot has created puppeteer code.  If it needs fixin' you should learn puppeteer.
